# Custom section In system configuration not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, configuration, system.xml

I created a module as suggested in another question:

`app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vendor_Module>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Vendor_Module>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <shippinginfo translate="label" module="module">
            <label>YOUR_LABEL</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>                    
                <shipping_times>
                    <fields>
                        <monday translate="label">
                            <label>Monday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </monday>
                        <tuesday translate="label">
                            <label>Tuesday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </tuesday>
                        <wednesday translate="label">
                            <label>Wednesday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </wednesday>
                        <thursday translate="label">
                            <label>Thursday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </thursday>
                        <friday translate="label">
                            <label>Friday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </friday>
                        <saturday translate="label">
                            <label>Saturday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>Leave blank If its non shipping day</comment>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </saturday>
                        <sunday translate="label">
                            <label>Sunday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>Leave blank If its non shipping day</comment>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sunday>                           
                    </fields>
                </shipping_times>
            </groups>
        </shippinginfo>
    </section>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/helper/data.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

I did refresh the cache, but there is no "YOUR_LABEL" in the "general" tab. 
What could be done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is typo in `system.xml`. The closing `</section>` should be `</sections>` *(missing "s" at the end)*.

And in `config.xml`

```
<helpers>
    <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
</helpers>
```

should be

```
<helpers>
    <vendor_module>
        <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
    </vendor_module>
</helpers>
```

**Edit:**

Helper isn't called correctly, change

```
<shippinginfo translate="label" module="module">
```

to

```
<shippinginfo translate="label" module="vendor_module">
```

Btw ... file/folder names should start with an uppercase letter:

```
app/code/local/Vendor/Module/helper/data.php
```

should be

```
app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php
```

**Edit 2:**

There are some lines missing:

```
<groups>                    
    <shipping_times>
```

should be

```
<groups>                    
    <shipping_times>
        <label>YOUR_GROUP_LABEL</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

**Edit 3:**

Missing ACL ... add to `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <shippinginfo>
                                        <title>Shippinginfo ACL</title>
                                    </shippinginfo>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did everything as you said, but I am getting an error: `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Module_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp64\www\magento1\app\Mage.php`. I tried reading on what might be causing it, but none of the cases seemed to apply to my case.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Interesting... I updated the code, now there are no errors, but I still don't see my custom tab.

Comment: Updated .... and tested :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I do see "YOUR_LABEL" now, but when I click on it, it gives me "404 error", have I made a mistake somewhere? Should I update my code in the question so you can see if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I already had ACL set for testing ;) See next (final) update :) Maybe you need to flush cache and log out and in.

Comment: So, if I don't have it already, I should create an `adminhtml.xml`?

Comment: I did create an `adminhtml.xml` file, but I still get the same "404" error... Is it possible for you to post the final code for all of the files? Thank you bearing with me.

Comment: Flushed cache? Logged out an in? If not working pls post full code.

Comment: Amazing! logging out and in did it! You are my hero! Thank you so much:)